# Python: Make a file temporarily unexecutable

Tags: windows, python-3.x

I'm writing a simple antivirus that checks for very specific files and patterns, and something I want to implement is a way to make a named file unexecuteable. By this I mean that the computer will realize that the file exists, and has a file extension that would usually launch an application or it's own code, but will not be able to execute it until the user gives the ok.

So given the filename, how could I make a file unable to be executed by the windows operating system?

Comment: For regular executables you can add an ACE to the file security descriptor that denies `FILE_EXECUTE` access to Everyone. (This requires a filesystem that supports security, such as NTFS or ReFS.) Other files such as scripts get executed indirectly. You'd have to deny `FILE_READ_DATA` access to prevent reading a script.

Comment: I'll try it out, thanks.